# Maven ERROR: package javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: maven, servlets

I am starting on a legacy project and trying to get it to build using Maven. I'm using Eclipse EE and Tomcat v7.0. The error in the Title line above arises when I run "mvn package" in Terminal. This error is really stumping me because in my pom.xml file I have the following dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also checked in the Properties>Targeted Runtimes and made sure Tomcat v7.0 is the selected runtime. I'm fairly certain it's a problem with my eclipse environment, and would like some suggestions on how to fix it.

EDIT: Here's some additional information. The first output after I run "mvn package" is

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myProject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

This is followed by another strange error that I forgot to include in the original posting. I say it's weird because, like the package javax.servlet, org.apache.catalina should also be included in tomcat

```
[ERROR] /path/to/Main.java:[7,26] error: package org.apache.catalina does not exist
```

Also, I think I mixed up the meaning of legacy project, because this isn't an old project. It's just a project that already had a lot of work done on that I'm now helping the original creator with.

Answer (score 5):

The dependency you're missing is probably the [*Servlet API*](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Be sure to import the correct version of the API. For a legacy project, that could be an older version than *2.5*.

As mentionned by *Grzegorz*, you should also use the scope *provided* since the Servlet API should be provided by your application server (e.g. Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

Add server runtime to your project. 
Example - for Tomcat

1 - right click on your project

2- select build path

3- Go to Libraries tab

4- Add Library

5- Select Server Run time

6- Here you should get the Apache Tomcat

[image]

If you don't get Apache Tomcat in here you need to add your server in Project Facets as below -

1- right click on your project

2- Select Project Facets

3- If you dont get options click on the link 'Convert to faceted form'

4- Go to Runtime tab at right side and select your runtime

[image]

Comment: While this is a nice answer on how to get Eclipse running, above is not related to maven build errors.